# Creating a new spreadsheet in google docs

Tags: c#, gdata, google-docs-api

We are trying to add a new Spreadsheet to google docs.

We use .Net 4.0.5 and the GData.Documents 2.2.0

We recently changed our authentication method to OAuth2 and we can perform actions like query spreadsheets etc.

our SCOPE is `https:// spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https:// docs.google.com/feeds https:// www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`

Our old code for creating a spreadsheet is:

```
   DocumentsService docService = new DocumentsService("Application");
   DocumentEntry entry = new DocumentEntry();
   docService.setUserCredentials("my_email@gmail.com", "PASSWORD");
   entry.Title.Text = "AddingNewSpreadsheet";
   entry.Categories.Add(DocumentEntry.SPREADSHEET_CATEGORY);
   DocumentEntry newEntry =   service.Insert(DocumentsListQuery.documentsBaseUri, entry);
```

We tried to change the code according to the new authentication method, but none of our attempts succeeded (400 bad request).

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer available in Google Sheets API (refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#creating_a_spreadsheet_1)). Creating a new spreadsheet file it would be via Google Drive API.

I recommend taking a look at the reference document for [Create Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-create) in the Drive API documentation. There are some examples with .NET sample code that can guide you through this. Hope this helps.